# Writing to csv error handling

Tags: python, json, csv

Currently my process works as follows:

1. Builds and sends requests to API
2. Receives responses
3. Parses JSON responses
4. Writes parsed values to csv

I am receiving a JSON response from the Google Directions API. My code works fine 99% of the time, but fails if I don't receive a JSON array as expected. Since I write the responses in bulk to csv after this loop, if an error occurs, I loose all of the results.

The code as is follows:

```
import requests
import csv
import json
import urlparse
import hashlib
import base64
import hmac
import sys
import time
from pprint import pprint

url_raw = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json'
Private_Key = ''
client = ''
decodedkey = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(Private_Key)

with open('./Origins.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    origincoords = ['{Y},{X}'.format(**row) for row in reader]

with open('./Destinations.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    destinationcoords = ['{Y},{X}'.format(**row) for row in reader]

results=[]
session = requests.session()

for origin, destination in zip(origincoords, destinationcoords):
    params ={'origin': origin, 'destination': destination, 'client': client}
    request = requests.Request('GET', url_raw, params=params).prepare()
    parsed_url = urlparse.urlparse(request.url)
    Signature = hmac.new(decodedkey, '{}?{}'.format(parsed_url.path, parsed_url.query), hashlib.sha1).digest() 
    request.prepare_url(request.url, {'signature': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(Signature)})
    response = session.send(request)
    directions = response.json()
    time.sleep(0.0)
    results.append(directions)

pprint(results)

output = open('duration_distance_results.csv', 'w+')
writer = csv.DictWriter(output, delimiter=',', fieldnames=['duration(s)', 'distance(m)'])
writer.writeheader()

for route in results:
    for leg in route['routes'][0]['legs']:
        params = {
            "duration(s)": leg['duration']['value'],
            "distance(m)": leg['distance']['value'],
        }
        print(params)
        writer.writerow(params)
```

If I don't get a JSON response back in the array expected, I get a list index out of range error and through this loose what had already been done up to this point.

Ideally, I think it would be more robust if I wrote to csv within the loop, as each result is received, rather than doing that after all of the results have been received. Or, as I have attempted, use if statements -

1. I have attempted an if statement, where if a value exists, write the value, if it doesn't, write error. However, I get the following error "NameError: name 'leg' is not defined"

   if leg in route['routes'][0]['legs'] == value:
       for route in results:
           for leg in route['routes'][0]['legs']:
               params = {
               "duration(s)": leg['duration']['value'],
               "distance(m)": leg['distance']['value'],
               }
               print(params)
               writer.writerow(params)

   else:
       for value in results:
           error = {
           "duration(s)": 'error',
           "distance(m)": 'error',
           }
           print(error)
           writer.writerow(error)
2. I attempted an if statement which looks at the status message returned from Google. However, this fails with the error "for error_message in results['results'][0]['error_message']:
   TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str"

   for error_message in results['results'][0]['error_message']:
       params = { "error_message": error_message}

   ```
   if error_message == value:
       for route in results:
           for leg in route['routes'][0]['legs']:
               params = {
               "duration(s)": leg['duration']['value'],
               "distance(m)": leg['distance']['value'],
               }
               print(params)
               writer.writerow(params)

   else:
       for value in results:
           error = {
           "duration(s)": 'error',
           "distance(m)": 'error',
           }
           print(error)
           writer.writerow(error)
   ```

   pprint(results)

As is obvious, Im learning slowly here. Comments on the best way to handle errors would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first obvious thing to do would be to check the HTTP status code for the `response` object. It's not an explicit part of the Google API documentation but obviously something else than a 200 ("Found") HTTP status code means you have a problem and you cannot even expect to get anything useful in the response's body. HTTP response codes are documented in the HTTP RFC.

Then if you read the API's documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/), you'll find out that the returned json dict has a 'status' key, which values are documented too. So the next obvious thing to check this status code, and behave appropriately, ie:

```
for result in results: 
    if result["status"] == "OK":
        for leg in result['routes'][0]['legs']:
            params = {
              "duration(s)": leg['duration']['value'],
              "distance(m)": leg['distance']['value'],
            }
            print(params)
            writer.writerow(params)
    else: 
      # not OK, let's check if we have an explicit error message:
      if "error_message" in result:
          print result["error_message"]
      # handle the error case...
```

Comment: Thank you @bruno. This worked well. Ive just ran 20,000 with no issues, excellent result